# Is Lagrange interpolating polynomial unique on a region?

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

Let's say I have some polynomial of degree $n$, call this $f(x)$ defined on a region [a,b].

If I find the Lagrange interpolating polynomial $P_{n}(x)$ given $n+1$ nodes from a to b, must $P_{n}(x) = f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ which agrees with $f$ at the $n+1$ points, and it is the only such polynomial.

$f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ wich agrees with $f$ at the $n+1$ points.

Therefore $P_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ must be identical.

Comment: Thank you! Follow-up question: What then is the advantage of using the Lagrange interpolating polynomial if we already know $f$?

Comment: Is it more useful for cases where $f$ is not a polynomial?

Comment: @theta Well, I don't know too much Numerical Analysis, but yes we usually use it when $f$ is usually not a polynomial. (Well really we have theorems involving general function $f$, and then someimes $f$ might happen to be a polynomial). But I imagine if you're studying polynoials, there might be some use somewhere or writing that polynomial in Lagrange form.

Comment: Rather than 'at most' $n$, shouldn't it say '$n$'?

Comment: @masiewpao Nope, it's "at most $n$". Consider if we choose to interpolate $11$ points, but our $f(x)$ happens to be a line, $f(x) = 2x+3$. The interpolating polynomial will be $p(x) = f(x)$ which has degree $1$, not $10$. And $f$ itself doesn't have to be a line. It can by curvy in between the nodes; but as long as at the nodes it follows the pattern of a line, our interpolating polynomial cannot distinguish $f$ from a line.

Comment: @Blue Ah yes that makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: @masiewpao Sure!